# How to avoid setting up a cron if already there

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

I am setting up a cron using the following command

`crontab -l | { cat; echo -e "#Adding cron task to execute imz script \n0 */1 * * * /usr/local/sbin/generate_imz_report.sh"; } | crontab -`

through a shell script. Everytime I execute the script it adds a new entry for this script

```
xyx.local: ~ # crontab -l
#Adding cron task to execute imz script
0 */1 * * * /usr/local/sbin/generate_imz_report.sh
#Adding cron task to execute imz script
0 */1 * * * /usr/local/sbin/generate_imz_report.sh
#Adding cron task to execute imz script
0 */1 * * * /usr/local/sbin/generate_imz_report.sh
#Adding cron task to execute imz script
0 */1 * * * /usr/local/sbin/generate_imz_report.sh
#Adding cron task to execute imz script
0 */1 * * * /usr/local/sbin/generate_imz_report.sh
#Adding cron task to execute imz script
0 */1 * * * /usr/local/sbin/generate_imz_report.sh
```

To avoid this I tried the following

`grep '#Adding cron task to execute imz script' /etc/crontab || crontab -l | { cat; echo -e "#Adding cron task to execute imz script \n0 */1 * * * /usr/local/sbin/generate_imz_report.sh"; } | crontab -`

But this does not work. How can I avoid adding  cron entry if already there in a shell script?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the cron file if the cron job you are adding is already there

```
SCRIPT="generate_imz_report.sh"
if crontab -l | grep $SCRIPT > /dev/null ; then
    echo "Cron job already installed."
else
    crontab -l > newcronjobs                                       # Write out old crontab
    echo "0 */1 * * * /usr/local/sbin/$SCRIPT" >> newcronjobs      # Append new cron job into cron file
    crontab newcronjobs                                            # Install new cron file
    rm newcronjobs
    echo "New cron job is added to crontab!!"
fi
```

Comment: @kyodev; Didn't get you?

Comment: it's annoying when the person does not have the courage to explain himself (that's what I wanted to say, sorry for my english).  
I have observed some who distributes more downvotes than they do answers...easy :(

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about the location of the crontab file "/etc/crontab" ? 
Why do you not try

```
$( crontab -l | grep 'generate_imz_report' ) || crontab -l | { cat; echo -e "#Adding cron task to execute imz script \n0 */1 * * * /usr/local/sbin/generate_imz_report.sh"; } | crontab -
```